# Date conversion in a XML column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

How do I convert the below mentioned XML code date format.

```
<StartDate>2015-12-24T00:00:00</StartDate>
<EndDate>2015-12-29T15:39:20</EndDate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several correct answers, but I've got the feeling, that these answers don't hit your actual issue:

> In my table there is a xml column, and that xml column contains somuch data including date, And i want to update those dates to date format like '2/28/2017' now the date format is like '2012-04-26T00:00:00'

If I got you correctly you want to change the stored dates within your XML to another format, correct?

Simple answer: **Don't!**

ISO8601 is the standard format for date/time values within XML. The format you would like more `2/28/2017` is culture related and could lead to errors, or even worse!, to wrong values, if day and month both are below 13: `04/05/2017` can be taken as 4th of May or as 5th of April. You should never rely on culture settings!

XML is not meant to be human readable. Or in better words: It is meant to be human readable for technical people only... It is a standardizes string representation of structured, complex documents. The format of values should not bother you! Use an appropriate editor for the **presentation**.

Answer (score 2):

If you're accessing your XML content with the built-in XQuery functionality, you can just use the `.value()` method and define the output datatype to be a `DATETIME2(3)` type - no special treatment necessary:

```
DECLARE @InputTbl TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlContent XML)

INSERT INTO @InputTbl (ID, XmlContent)
VALUES (1, '<Root>
<StartDate>2015-12-24T00:00:00</StartDate>
<EndDate>2015-12-29T15:39:20</EndDate>
</Root>');

SELECT
    StartDate = XC.value('(StartDate)[1]', 'datetime2(3)'),
    EndDate = XC.value('(EndDate)[1]', 'datetime2(3)')
FROM
    @InputTbl
CROSS APPLY
    XmlContent.nodes('/Root') AS XT(XC)
```

This returns this output:

[image]

Comment: @coder1991 sorry, i want to update these xml fields to another table.and this is not a two lined code this is a huge xml code. I want to update all date to date time format.

Comment: <XmlColumn>
      <ID>123</ID>
      <FieldName>11</FieldName>
      <Text>November</Text>
      <Value>True</Value>
    </XmlColumn>
    <XmlColumn>
      <ID>124</ID>
      <FieldName>12</FieldName>
      <Text>December</Text>
      <Value>True</Value>
    </XmlColumn>
  </MonthsOfYear>
  <DaysInMonth>
    <XmlColumn>
      <ID>131</ID>
      <FieldName>07</FieldName>
      <Text>7</Text>
      <Value>True</Value>
    </XmlColumn>
  </DaysInMonth>
  <NamesOfWeekInMonth />
</Frequency>
<StartDate>2009-11-07T00:00:00</StartDate> This is the sample code

Comment: @junaib: please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
DECLARE @X XML ='<StartDate>2015-12-24T00:00:00</StartDate>
<EndDate>2015-12-29T15:39:20</EndDate>'


SELECT   @X.value('/StartDate[1]','DATETIME') AS START_DTE
        ,@X.value('/EndDate[1]','DATETIME') AS END_DTE

+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|        START_DTE        |         END_DTE         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2015-12-24 00:00:00.000 | 2015-12-29 15:39:20.000 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

**Update:** From comments

The Datatime format in XML follows the ***ISO8601*** standards. And you are thinking to format it native SQL format, which is not correct that you are treating XML like normal text data. The data present in XML format is correct. And If you want you can convert it to native SQL as above mentioned.

There is a good info at Wikipedia [ISO 8601(Combined date and time representations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
on how the XML hold date time data.

> A single point in time can be represented by concatenating a complete
>   date expression, the letter T as a delimiter, and a valid time
>   expression. For example, "2007-04-05T14:30".

Comment: How doi convert and  update the StartDate and EndDate same time in that huge xml code

Comment: @junaib It is very hard to tell without sample data and desired output. These links might help you [replace value of (XML DML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/replace-value-of-xml-dml)  , [modify() Method (xml Data Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/modify-method-xml-data-type)

Comment: In my table there is a xml column, and that xml column contains somuch data including date, And i want to update those dates to date format like '2/28/2017' now the date format is like '2012-04-26T00:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

This might be work

```
declare @date ='2015-12-24T00:00:00 2015-12-29T15:39:20'
SELECT CONVERT(date, Left(@date,10)) as NewDate
```

Comment: By converting to a `DATE`, you're removing the time portion of the `@date` - this might not be a desired behavior....

Comment: yes for a complete datetime  format just : SELECT CONVERT(date, @date) as NewDate